# Embedded subgroups are automatically Lie subgroups.

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Here is a proposition from Lee's ISM:

[image]

I wonder why the restriction of multiplication to $H\times H$ is clearly smooth. It doesn't seem so obvious to me. The thing is, I don't know how to deal with the product $H\times H$. Is it an embedded submanifold of $G\times G$? Thank you.

Comment: Restrictions of smooth maps to submanifolds are always smooth, for example by the Rank Theorem, Theorem 4.12 in Lee's book. The delicate part is to prove that indeed multiplication is smooth as a map with codomain $H$, but for this you just use Corollary 5.30, as Lee mentions.
Next, do the same with the inverse map.

Comment: I have learned Theorem 5.27, but how do I know $H\times H$ is a submanifold? Thank you.

Comment: $H$ is a submanifold of $G$, this implies that the inclusion $\iota: H \hookrightarrow G$ is smooth. Thus, clearly the inclusion $\iota\times\iota: H\times H \hookrightarrow G\times G$ is smooth, hence $H\times H$ is a submanifold of $G\times G$.